# Setting properties using asp-for in MVC Core App with EF Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, ef-core-3.1

As I understand it from these docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1 , asp-for is used to transfer values from input elements to backend C# class properties, for example:

```
<input type="text" id="wsite" name="wsite" maxlength="11" asp-for="WebsiteName">
```

Along with '@folderName ClassName;' at the top, lets you transfer to this example property:

```
public string WebsiteName { get; set; }
```

However, testing this out with console.WriteLine show that the property is still null after the form containing the input has been submitted. Any idea what I'm missing?

Edit: Updated to show my property name and asp-for value match, and to add my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post()
    {
        DBCRUD.Initialize(_context);
        return NoContent();
    }
```

Comment: Can you please show us the controller action that will receive the data submitted?

Comment: Updated my original post to show Controller.

Answer (score 0):

The asp-for tag should match the variable-name.

Try defining your html-form like:

```
@model Classname
<form asp-action="ActionName" asp-controller="ControllerName" ...>

<input type="text" asp-for="VarName">
```

and your controller:

```
public MyReturnVariable ActionName(ClassName class) {
    Console.WriteLine(class.VarName);
}
```

Comment: Updated my original post to show Controller. Also using Console.WriteLine in the controller gives an 'unreachable code' error.

Answer (score 0):

The Tag Helpers is used with Model binding and creating and rendering HTML elements(display the model properties) in the web page.

So, in the Web page (or view page), at the top of the header,  we should add the following code to assign the model.

```
@model MVCSample.Models.BookModel
```

Then, using the following code to display the properties:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="AddBook">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ID" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ID" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ID" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="bookName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="bookName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="bookName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code in the controller:

```
    [HttpGet] 
    public IActionResult AddBook()
    {
        BookModel book = new BookModel()
        {
            ID = 1001,
            bookName = "War and Peace",
            Title = "War and Peace"
        };
        return View(book);
    }
```

Code in the model:

```
public class BookModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string bookName { get; set; } 
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

More details information, you could check the [Model Binding](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding).

Comment: The link you added appears to be specific to Razor Pages, which I'm not using. Also a lot of superfluous code in your answer. Appreciate the reply, though.

Comment: Edit: I now understand model binding can be used outside of Razor pages, so thanks!